# Stack pointer in assembly moves more than the required number of bytes for storage of auto variables

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Quoting from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames),

> For many compilers, the standard function entry sequence is the
>   following piece of code (X is the total size, in bytes, of all
>   automatic variables used in the function):
>
> ```
> push ebp
> mov ebp, esp
> sub esp, X
> ```

I am in Visual Studio 2015, 64 bit Intel Processor machine. I am examining a very simple main function via disassembly where even though I only have two auto variables, esp ends up allocating a lot more (216 bytes) than the space for two variables. Relevant code appears below.

```
int main() {
00E61650  push        ebp  
00E61651  mov         ebp,esp  
00E61653  sub         esp,0D8h ; why is esp being decremented by 0D8h
                               ;which is decimal for 216 even though there
                               ;are only two auto variables, a and b?
00E61659  push        ebx  
00E6165A  push        esi  
00E6165B  push        edi  
00E6165C  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]  
00E61662  mov         ecx,36h  
00E61667  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00E6166C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    int a = 5;
00E6166E  mov         dword ptr [a],5  
    int b = a + 6;
00E61675  mov         eax,dword ptr [a]  
00E61678  add         eax,6  
00E6167B  mov         dword ptr [b],eax  
    return 0;
00E6167E  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

Do auto variables in main() require more memory than auto variables in other functions?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I could not find that earlier even though I searched. Will delete this question.

Comment: You should not, duplicate are useful to other people who ask something close to you but not close with the original question. Duplicate are not always bad question.